# Not able to access shared path in powershell

Tags: sql-server, powershell

I want to take a SQL DB backup to a shared path and perform restoration through PS. Below is the code to perform the op

```
function restore-TemporaryInLocal($dbName,$backupPath,$sqlServer,$isOverWrite,$DecDBObj,$sqlInstanceName)
{

    $percentEventHandler = [Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.PercentCompleteEventHandler] { Write-Host "Restoration progress : " $_.Percent "%" }
    $completedEventHandler = [Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Common.ServerMessageEventHandler] { Write-Host $_.Error.Message}
    # Get the default file and log locations
    # (If DefaultFile and DefaultLog are empty, use the MasterDBPath and MasterDBLogPath values)
    $DataFileLoc = $sqlServer.Settings.DefaultFile
    $LogFileLoc = $sqlServer.Settings.DefaultLog
    if ($DataFileLoc.Length -eq 0) {
        $DataFileLoc = $sqlServer.Information.MasterDBPath
        }
    if ($LogFileLoc.Length -eq 0) {
        $LogFileLoc = $sqlServer.Information.MasterDBLogPath
        }

    # Identify the backup file to use, and the name of the database copy to create
    #$BackupFile= 'D:\SQLJobs\Errdb2.bak'
    #$RestoredDBName = 'ErrDB2_20101016'

    # Build the physical file names for the database copy
    $DBFile = $DataFileLoc + $dbname + '_Data.mdf'
    $LogFile = $LogFileLoc + $dbname + '_Log.ldf'

    # Use the backup file name to create the backup device
    $bdi = new-object ('Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.BackupDeviceItem') ($backupPath, 'File')

    # Create the new restore object, set the database name and add the backup device
    $restoreObj = new-object('Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.Restore') 
    $restoreObj.Database = $dbName
    $restoreObj.Devices.Add($bdi)

    # Get the file list info from the backup file
    $FileList = $restoreObj.ReadFileList($sqlServer)
    foreach ($file in $FileList) {
        $rsfile = new-object('Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.RelocateFile')
        $rsfile.LogicalFileName = $file.LogicalName
        if ($file.Type -eq 'D'){
            $rsfile.PhysicalFileName = $DBFile
        }
        else {
            $rsfile.PhysicalFileName = $LogFile
        }
        $restoreObj.RelocateFiles.Add($rsfile)
        }

    # Restore the database

    $restoreObj.ReplaceDatabase=$isOverWrite;
    #Write-Host "Replace DB :"$restoreObj.ReplaceDatabase
    $restoreObj.add_PercentComplete($percentEventHandler)
    $restoreObj.add_Complete($completedEventHandler)
    if($isOverWrite -eq $true)
    {
        Write-Host "Taking DB Offline";
        $script="ALTER DATABASE $dbname SET OFFLINE WITH ROLLBACK IMMEDIATE";
        #Write-Host $script $dbname $sqlInstanceName
        Invoke-SQLcmd -Server $sqlInstanceName -Database $dbName $script
        Write-Host "Getting DB Online";
        $DecDBObj.SetOnline();

    }
    Write-Host "Initiating DB restore..."
    $restoreObj.SqlRestore($sqlServer) 
}

function take-BackupToLocal($backupDirectory,$serverName,$backupDB,$isCopyOnly,$serverRef)
{
    [System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("Microsoft.SqlServer.SMO") | Out-Null
    [System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("Microsoft.SqlServer.SmoExtended") | Out-Null
    [System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("Microsoft.SqlServer.ConnectionInfo") | Out-Null
    [System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("Microsoft.SqlServer.SmoEnum") | Out-Null
    $percentEventHandler = [Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.PercentCompleteEventHandler] { Write-Host "Database backed up" $_.Percent "%" }
    $completedEventHandler = [Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Common.ServerMessageEventHandler] { Write-Host $_.Error.Message
    Write-Host "Backup Path:"$targetPath
    }
    $dbList = $serverRef.Databases
    $BackupDB =$BackupDB.Trim();
    $DBexists=$false;
    if(test-path $backupDirectory)
    {
        $timestamp = Get-Date -format yyyy-MM-dd-HHmmss
        $targetPath = $backupDirectory + "\" + $backupDB + "_" + $timestamp + ".bak"
        foreach ($database in $dbList | where { $_.IsSystemObject -eq $False })
        {  
            $dbName = $database.Name
            if($database.Name -eq $BackupDB -and $database.Status -ieq "normal"){
                $DBexists=$true;
                $smoBackup = New-Object ("Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.Backup")
                $smoBackup.Action = "Database"
                $smoBackup.BackupSetDescription = "Full Backup of " + $dbName
                $smoBackup.BackupSetName = $dbName + " Backup"
                $smoBackup.Database = $dbName
                $smoBackup.MediaDescription = "Disk"
                $smoBackup.CopyOnly=$isCopyOnly
                $smoBackup.Devices.AddDevice($targetPath, "File")
                $smoBackup.PercentCompleteNotification=5
                $smoBackup.add_PercentComplete($percentEventHandler)
                $smoBackup.add_Complete($completedEventHandler)
                $smoBackup.SqlBackup($serverRef)
                return $targetPath;
            }else{
                Write-Host "Cannot perform a backup as the DB is in:" $database.Status " mode"; 
            }
        }
        if($DBexists -eq $false)
        {
            Write-Host "$BackupDB DB not found in $serverName.Please check the DB & Server details"
        }
    }
    else
    {
        Write-Host "Cannot find the path specified. Contact admin"
        Write-Host "backup path:"$backupDirectory
    }
}



$sqlName= "*************"
$serverName="******";
# Set new or existing databse name to restote backup
$backupDB= "AdventureWorksDW2012"

# Set the existing backup file path
#$backupPath= "D:\Automation\Ps-scripts\Backups\tempdb1_2017-05-25-222232.bak"

#Load the required assemlies SMO and SmoExtended.
[System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("Microsoft.SqlServer.SMO") | Out-Null
[System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("Microsoft.SqlServer.SmoExtended") | Out-Null
$percentEventHandler = [Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.PercentCompleteEventHandler] { Write-Host "Restoration progress : " $_.Percent "%" }
$completedEventHandler = [Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Common.ServerMessageEventHandler] { Write-Host $_.Error.Message}
try{
    # Connect SQL Server.
    $sqlServer = New-Object ('Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.Server') $sqlName
    $ExistingDB=$sqlServer.Databases.Item($backupDB) 
    $backupDirectory="\\***********\ps_jobs_backup_shared";
    $isCopyOnly=$true;
   if($ExistingDB.EncryptionEnabled -eq $true)
    {
        $needToDecrypt = Read-Host -Prompt 'Specify if backup needs to be decrypted (Y/N)'
    }
    if($needToDecrypt -ieq "y")
    {
        #Write-Host "decryption code...."
        $decServerSqlName="***************"
        Write-Host "Initiating Backup..."
        $DecryptDB="tempDB1"
        $decSqlServer = New-Object ('Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.Server') $decServerSqlName
        $decServerSqlName="****************"
        $isOverWrite=$true;
        $DecDBObj=$decSqlServer.Databases.Item($DecryptDB) 
        $backupPath=take-BackupToLocal -backupDirectory $backupDirectory -serverName $sqlName -backupDB $backupDB -isCopyOnly $isCopyOnly -serverRef $sqlServer 
        restore-TemporaryInLocal -dbName $DecryptDB -backupPath $backupPath -sqlServer $decSqlServer -isOverWrite $isOverWrite -DecDBObj $DecDBObj -sqlInstanceName $decServerSqlName

    }elseif($needToDecrypt -ieq "n")
    {
        Write-Host "Initiating a encrypted backup...";
        take-BackupToLocal -backupDirectory $backupDirectory -serverName $sqlName -backupDB $backupDB -isCopyOnly $isCopyOnly -serverRef $sqlServer
    }
}
catch 
{
    $_.Exception.GetBaseException().Message
}
```

Now the above code works fine. However when I execute the same code once again the TEST-PATH conditions fails[work-around: Need to re-open the PS IDE again after every run]

Below is the log for first 2 runs.

```
Specify if backup needs to be decrypted (Y/N): y
Initiating Backup...
Database backed up 5 %
Database backed up 10 %
Database backed up 100 %
BACKUP DATABASE successfully processed 25625 pages in 8.435 seconds (23.733 MB/sec).
Taking DB Offline
Getting DB Online
Initiating DB restore...
Restoration progress :  10 %
Restoration progress :  20 %
Restoration progress :  100 %
RESTORE DATABASE successfully processed 25625 pages in 7.429 seconds (26.946 MB/sec).
```

2nd Run:

```
Specify if backup needs to be decrypted (Y/N): y
Initiating Backup...
Cannot find the path specified. Contact admin
backup path: \\sanky555\ps_jobs_backup_shared
```

Comment: Code dumps are hard to debug. Try printing the `$backupDirectory` variable in the error message too, so you'd see what path is actually used.

Comment: @vonPryz I have edited the question with the requested data and I am able to see the path in the error section